# Variable event in Java

Tags: java, compilation

I'm having a problem with a Klondike Solitaire I'm programming. It's almost finished but now when I try to compile (I'm using Dr. Java, yeah I know), it keeps popping up with 2 errors.

1. Cannot find symbol: Variable event
2. Cannot find symbol: Method "findbunki" (java.awt.Point)

I've already imported java.awt, so that can't be it.

Answer (score 2):

Without code this would be my guess:

1) you use a variable named 'event' but it is not one of the arguments in you method. (Alternatively: you forgot to declare it, but from the name I'd guess it's belongs in a method call)

2) You call the method 'findbunki' on an object of type java.awt.Point - Point does not have that method. Find the class that has the fundbunki method (probably one of your own classes) and call the method on an object of that type.

Answer (score 0):

You should be import java.awt.event.*;